# Async function that returns a Promise or String - Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to return not just a Promise from a function?

```
const someFunc = async <T>(url: string): Promise<T> => {
  const res = await fetch(url);

  if (!res.ok) return { error: 'error text' };
  return await res.json();
}
```

Depending on the condition, function above can return a promise or an object with `{ error: 'string' }`. I'm getting an error here: `TS2322: Type '{ error: any; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.   '{ error: any; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.`

I've tried to use:

```
const someFunc = async <T>(url: string): Promise<T> | Promise<string> => {}
```

This throws an error: `TS1055: Type 'Promise<T> | Promise<string>' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.`

Also i've tried this variant:

```
const someFunc = async <T>(url: string): Promise<T | { error: string }> => {}
```

But when i consume this function:

```
interface IResponse {
  access_token: string;
  refresh_token: string;
  userRoles: string[];
  error: any;
}

const result = await someFunc<IResponse>(url);
console.log(result.access_token); // throws an error
// TS2339: Property 'access_token' does not exist on type '{ error: string; } | IResponse'.   Property 'access_token' does not exist on type '{ error: string; }'.
```

**UPDATE with type guard**

```
If ('access_token' in result) {
  console.log(result.access_token);
}
```

this works fine, uses `access_token` from `IResponse` interface.

Comment: _"The `async` function declaration defines an asynchronous function — a function that returns an `AsyncFunction` object. Asynchronous functions operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event loop, returning an **implicit `Promise` as its result**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

Comment: Why are you using a generic here?

Comment: @voiys because i would reuse this function and depends on endpoint it would have a different response shape? Isn't obvious?

Comment: @voiys for better or worse it is a common pattern with functions that return objects from the network to specify the expected type of the result as a type parameter. It's no better than a type assertion but slightly more convenient.

Comment: Im just beginning to learn ts so im wondering :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type for an async should be a `Promise`, but the result type of the `Promise` can be a union:

```
const someFunc = async <T>(url: string): Promise<T | { error: string}> => {
  const res = await fetch(url);

  if (!res.ok) return { error: 'error text' };
  return await res.json();
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmYMC8MCGEAnpjADwAqAfABRoBOANgFxxR0CWYA5gJQsAKdROwhIKMAD4wA3jCR0hdFtA7cAvpRybpAKBgxQkWHSQQc+AO552sAGZIowABa1GPANw69MdrZjUAQhMIADoQAGseGBMoejAZOQUQJRgAcnlFGCgkAA8oVJg1T30YuMtrY1MQgCt4MGoPHTUgA)

To use the function result you will need to narrow the type of the result to see if it is an error or the actual result:

```
interface IResponse {
  access_token: string;
  refresh_token: string;
  userRoles: string[];
}

async function test() {
  const result = await someFunc<IResponse>("url");
  if (!('error' in result)) {
    console.log(result.access_token);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmYMC8MCGEAnpjADwAqAfABRoBOANgFxxR0CWYA5gJQsAKdROwhIKMAD4wA3jCR0hdFtA7cAvpRybpAKBgxQkWHSQQc+AO552sAGZIowABa1GPANw69MdrZjUAQhMIADoQAGseGBMoejAZOQUQJRgAcnlFGCgkAA8oVJg1T30YuMtrY1MQgCt4MGoPHTUvTmy6WzxgJBgASQAlUwAHcFEZb06uiAgAfSgIpDBlNk4uYuikW2CnWfnF1lVV7zRROj6QBlMlg4BtAF1PZp0CYixbDGAodnAs0ygGsf0hmg6wgaAYsFweCsNjgiFQ71I-SGIyQNAARPQGGjGvpfP4AtR0kk6AVOCCwVAeFFdPpASNzkgQgwQFxqMEKSEJqYZnNwgscYUmkA)

See the section on [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) from the handbook

Comment: I made an update in my question, please, take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexanderKim That is normal, you need to then narrow the type of the result. How can you use `result` as `IResponse` if you don't know for sure it is not an error ? I will udpate the answer with a usage example shortly

Comment: Thanks, first time i heard about type guards. WebStorm suggested that to me, but i didn't understand what is it actually.

Comment: Could you explain, in my IRespoinse interface, i have `error: any`, if i `console.log(result.error)` it uses this interface, but why it doesn't use this interface with `result.access_token`? I also updated my working variant in my original question.

Comment: @AlexanderKim `error` would be a common property between `IResponse` and `{ error: string}` so it would be accessible, those are the rules of unions. I removed it in my code sample to so I could use it to discriminate between  `IResponse` and `{ error: string}`. You could leave `error` in and discriminate on property that is not in both types. (Ex  `if ('access_token' in result) {
    console.log(result.access_token);
  }`

Comment: if i delete error from IResponse, then `result.error` doesn't exist on type IResponse, can't wrap my head around this.